# Is it possible to set more than one "setDateStyle" for dates?

Tags: ios, nsdate

Is it possible to set more than one "setDateStyle" for dates? like "NSDateFormatterShortStyle, NSDateFormatterMediumStyle" because i need to enter both types of dates and need to accept both . Is it possible?

Comment: Define what you mean by "I need to enter both types of dates and need to accept both".

Comment: you have to create 2 different NSDateFormatters or you have have one and configure it differently each time you go to use it.  Create 2 different formatters in my opinion.

Comment: Actually i need to accept "NSDateFormatterShortStyle, NSDateFormatterMediumStyle, NSDateFormatterLongStyle, and NSDateFormatterFullStyle" strings. ie my app needs to accept these styles of input because each user use different formats.

Comment: Please provide a few sample date strings you need to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using `NSDataDetector` with `NSTextCheckingTypeDate`, that recognized many date formats.

```
NSString *dateText = @"march 31, 1945 12:34 pm";

NSError *error;
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeDate error:&error];
NSTextCheckingResult *result = [detector firstMatchInString:dateText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, dateText.length)];
NSDate *date = result.date;

NSString *reformattedDate = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
NSLog(@"reformattedDate: %@", reformattedDate);
```

NSLog output:

> reformattedDate date: Saturday, March 31, 1945 at 12:34:00 PM